# Select last cells with a value in a row - multiple cells

Tags: excel, select, row

I would like in my excel file select in several rows the last value. 
For example I have the macro:

```
Range("L834").Value = Range("IV834").End(xlToLeft).Value
Range("L836").Value = Range("IV836").End(xlToLeft).Value
Range("L837").Value = Range("IV837").End(xlToLeft).Value
Range("L839").Value = Range("IV839").End(xlToLeft).Value
```

This is select the row L834 to L839 and it appears in L834 the last value in the row.

I would like to find an easier way to group these ranges. I have tried:

```
Range("L834:L839").Value = Range("IV834:IV839").End(xlToLeft).Value
```

But it doesn't work actually.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: `Range("L834:L839").Value = Range("IV834").End(xlToLeft).Resize(6).Value` is it what you're trying?

Comment: Thank you it is working with your way.

Answer (score 0):

As follow up from comments this one works:

```
Range("L834:L839").Value = Cells(834,Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Resize(6).Value
```